# How to access static method id from GWT JSNI

Tags: java, gwt, jsni

I fail to get the request_id from MyJavaObject in GWT JSNI like this example but got undefined value.

Please help.

JAVA CLASS

```
package com.my.app;

    class MyJavaObject
    {
        public final int request_id;

        public MyJavaObject(int request_id)
        {
            this.request_id = request_id;
        }

        public static final MyJavaObject MY_REQUEST = new MyJavaObject(13);
    }
```

GWT JSNI

```
public static native void expose()/*-{

    var val = @com.my.app.MyJavaObject::MY_REQUEST.request_id;

}-*/;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access a non-static member variable from a static method without any reference to this object

Read the doc here: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#methods-fields, your method should be written like that:

```
public static native void expose()/*-{

    var val = this.@com.my.app.MyJavaObject::request_id;
    // Do something with val...
}-*/;
```

Edit after comment:

Maybe this could work:

```
public static native void expose()/*-{

    var val = @com.my.app.MyJavaObject::MY_REQUEST.@com.my.app.MyJavaObject::request_id;
    // Do something with val...
}-*/;
```

if it does not, pass your object as a parameter:

```
public static native void expose( MyJavaObject obj)/*-{

    var val = obj.@com.my.app.MyJavaObject::request_id;
    // Do something with val...
}-*/;
```

and either call `expose( MY_REQUEST )` directly or create a helper function

```
public static native void expose() {
    return expose( MY_REQUEST );
}
```

Comment: I has edited the jsni code. I want to get the static object MY_REQUEST.request_id

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that while you are referencing the full type where the `MY_REQUEST` field lives, you are *not* referencing the full type where the `request_id` lives. Since JS has a very different concept of type hierarchy, when we reference Java from JS, we need to be very specific.

When you referenced `MY_REQUEST`, you did so by using the @classname::fieldname syntax. You must also do this to get the `request_id` field:

```
public static native void expose()/*-{
  var myRequest = @com.my.app.MyJavaObject::MY_REQUEST;
  var id = myRequest.@com.my.app.MyJavaObject::request_id;
  //do something useful with these values...
}-*/;
```

This could also be achieved in one line, but tends to be unreadable, so I'd avoid it.